# Regex to truncate lines of text (replace with nothing)

Tags: .net, regex

I have a .NET-based tool that allows me to do a regex replace on lines in a file, but not a lot of other options (I say this because I know full well this is not the ideal tool for the job... it's just what I have to work with in this case).

I need to truncate the file at 95 characters for each line.  Each line has alphanumerics and whitespace.  I have the option of entering a matching expression and a replacement expression.  I expect I will make the replacement expression either nothing or a `\r\n`.

What can I use for my matching expression to select everything after the first 95 characters?

Comment: Do you know what regex features are in the tool? You mentioned that you don't think you have access to capture groups, which by the way is a pretty basic feature... Maybe the tool can handle it and you're not aware of it?

Comment: @Jerry it's certainly possible... this is a home-grown file transfer tool that added some rudimentary transformation functionality... one of our vendors requires lines to be exactly 95 characters.  I can add 95 spaces to each line pretty easily, but scraping off the excess is not so simple.

Comment: Well, then try Matt's suggestions. You can usually access capture groups with `$1` or `\1` (for the first capture group).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use substring to cut up strings, but if you want a regex, then something like:

```
^.{,95}
```

Will match the first 95 (or less if the string is shorter) characters on a string. Replace the `.` with something else if you want to restrict what types of characters it will match.

To get the characters after the first 95, you could do something like:

```
^.{,95}(.*)
```

Now the extra characters will be in a capture group.

Using a look behind you could do something like:

```
(?<=.{95})(.*)
```

Which will only match strings that are more than 95 characters.

Comment: I really don't have access to a capture group, I don't think.  Is there an expression that means "everything that is not in the first 95 characters" without resorting to capture groups?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Of course you have access to the capture group. That's silly. But if you don't want to use them, you can use a *look behind*

Comment: You were right, I was overthinking it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
([\s a-z A-Z 0-9]{1,95})(.*)
```

replace with:

```
\1
```